# Python Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm trying to create a simple program that waits for a file using sockets and then returns the output of that to a text field on another thread.

I have done some research and I know how the basics of threading works, but I don't understand how multiple threads can connect to each other.

My problem is that the `WindowManager.addText` function only gets updated on an event of the `WindowManager` class itself, and not from the `ConnectionManager` class. How can I fix this so every time `WindowManager.addText` is called on another thread it instantly gets updated?

I got a `WindowManager` class, which saves a string to a text field (loaded with GTK):

```
class WindowManager:
    def __init__(self):
        #Load the window here, not relevant
        self.textBuffer = self.messagePanel.get_buffer()
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def addText(self, text, *args):
        self.lock.acquire()        
        logging.debug('Waiting for lock')
        try:
            logging.debug('Acquired lock')
            self.textBuffer.insert_with_tags_by_name(self.textBuffer.get_end_iter(), text, *args)
        finally:
            self.lock.release()
```

Now I also got a `ConnectionManager` class here, which loads the connection thread:

```
class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self, windowManager):
        self.ping = PingThread(windowManager)
        self.ping.setDaemon(True)
        self.ping.start()
```

And finally I've got the `PingThread` class which is the actual connection thread, where for this example I call the thread randomly:

```
class PingThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,  window, group=None, target=None, name=None, verbose=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, group=group, target=target, name=name, verbose=verbose)
        self.window = window

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.window.addText("Test")
            time.sleep(random.randrange(1,10))
```

Comment: You never want to do GUI stuff in the non-GUI thread. The GUI thread should listen to a queue that `PingThread` creates.

Comment: Can you give explain that further? Because I don't really understand what you mean. The GUI is now on another thread, the main thread, as far as I know.

Comment: It is, but `PingThread` is trying to access the GUI in the main thread (`WindowManager`) with `self.window.addText("Test")`. This is the issue.

Comment: Yes I already had a feeling that that would be the problem, but how can I push the messages then?

Comment: With a queue, like I said. I don't really know how to do this in GTK, which is why I left a comment and not an answer. In Tkinter I often do this with the `Queue` stdlib module. I don't see why that wouldn't work here, but GTK might have their own convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching on Stack Overflow I found the answer. All I needed to do was initialize the threads by putting this at the beginning of my code: `GObject.threads_init()`